# Add Unity 2d panel to XFCE

Tags: 11.10, unity-2d, panel, xfce

How to add Unity 2d panel to XFCE environment, but only Unity 2d panel, not the dash

Comment: Any specific reason to? the XFCE seems to do pretty much the same as the Unity panel..

Comment: I like Unity 2d panel. I've set up global menu on xfce panel but it's not as nice as Unity 2d have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to run `unity-2d-panel` command . this will just give you the unity panel on the top.If you add this to startup then automatically it will run at startup everytime and you can add it with `session and startup` .

hope that helps.